# Google Meet: How to mute specific user

Tags: audio, google-meet

My wife is a school teacher and uses Google Meets to teach her classes. While teaching 30+ children, one or two of them have started spamming the chat and repeatedly making noises via the mic. Does anyone know how she, the host, can disable a particular participant's chat and mic without kicking that participant out of the meeting?

Comment: Does this help: https://support.google.com/meet/answer/7501121?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en

Comment: Thank you, K7AAY, I will try that.

Comment: @essjae Thank you, unfortunately the participant can reactivate their mic and continue spam the class.  I am looking for a way to lock out their mic and chat ability.

Answer (score 1):

First, click or tap on the People icon in the top right portion of the Google Meet window.

[image]

A menu that lists the meeting, participants will open up on the right side of the window. Click or tap on the name of the person you want to mute.

[image]

Three icons will pop up below the person’s name on the list. Tap on the middle icon, which looks like a microphone.

[image]

A warning will pop up reminding you that doing this will mute the person for everyone in the call and that the person you are muting is the only one who can unmute themselves.

If you want to go ahead and mute them, click or tap on the “Mute” button.

[image]

The person’s microphone will be turned off (muted), and everyone in the meeting will be notified. Remember, only the person that has been muted can unmute themselves.